# Python - test a function was called with context

Tags: python, testing, contextmanager

Say I have a context manager and a function which has to be called within this context.

```
with my_context_manager():
    my_function()
```

Is it possible to test that `my_function` was called in the context of `my_context_manager`?

Comment: There are lots of ways, but the best IMO is to make it take the context object as a required parameter, or even to make it a method on the context.  Is either of those possible?  Other options would involve ugly shared global state.

Comment: With *this* code, you would need to use the `inspect` module to examine the actual source code. The "context" is just a couple of methods that get called before and after the execution of the body, not any detectable change to the runtime environment.

Comment: Is this for a unit test, or do you want `my_function` to behave differently depending on whether `my_context_manager` is being used?

Comment: Yes, it's for a unit test. I suspected it would be tricky, like resorting to `inspect`, as you've pointed out above. I take "not [easily] possible" as an answer.